# Get Service selectors with K8s Python client

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to get Service `label selectors` through [Kubernetes Python Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). I am using [list_service_for_all_namespaces](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_service_for_all_namespaces) method to retrieve the services, and filter it with `field_selector` parameter like:

```
...
field_selector="spec.selector={u'app': 'redis'}
...
services = v1.list_service_for_all_namespaces(field_selector=field_selector, watch=False)
for service in services.items:
    print(service)
...
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"\"spec.selector\" is not a known field selector: only \"metadata.name\", \"metadata.namespace\"","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

So, it seems that only `name` and `namespace` are valid parameters, which is not documented:

> field_selector = 'field_selector_example' # str | A selector to restrict the list of returned objects by their fields. Defaults to everything. (optional)

For now my workaround is to set the same *labels* as *label selectors* to the service, then to retrieve it through `label_selector` parameter, but I'd like to be able to get it through `label selectors`.

The thing is that from the beginning I need to get the endpoints behind the service (the backend pods), but the API call is not even returning this information, so I though I would get the selectors, match them against the labels on the pods, and there we go, but now I am realizing the selectors are not possible to get either.

This is too much limitation. I am thinking may be my approach is wrong. Does anyone know a way of getting `label selectors` from a service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the selector from a service object, and then use that to find all the pods that match the selector.

For example (I am hoping I don't have typos, and my python is rusty):

```
services = v1.list_service_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for svc in services.items:
    if svc.spec.selector:
        # convert the selector dictionary into a string selector
        # for example: {"app":"redis"} => "app=redis"
        selector = ''
        for k,v in svc.spec.selector.items():
            selector += k + '=' + v + ','
        selector = selector[:-1]

        # Get the pods that match the selector
        pods = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(label_selector=selector)
        for pod in pods.items:
            print(pod.metadata.name)
```

Comment: This is working. But this is pure python skills. I was hoping the API to return this info somehow. Thank you!